# AngularJS, ng-repeat with ng-include not rendering

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, singlepage

Hi I am starting to learn angular and I'm running into a problem when I use a combination of ng-repeat with ng-include. No matter what I do I cannot get the templates to render. I have a simple controller that creates a list of workspaces and each workspace has a TemplateUrl property.

I know the value is correct because if I just render out the raw text {{workspace.TemplateUrl}} and then put that directly into the ng-include it works no problem.  It just never seems to work when its coming from the controller.  I have tried putting the template path in quotes like this too but it makes no difference.

```
$scope.Workspaces.push(new Workspace("'/app/templates/Template1.html'", "Workspace 1"));
```

When I run it I am seeing no requests to pull the template. Can anyone help on this as its driving me a little nuts.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
    <title>Workspaces</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <script src="app/libraries/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="app/libraries/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app/libraries/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="app/app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="HostController">
    <div>
        <ul class="unstyled">
            <li ng-repeat="workspace in Workspaces">
                <p>{{workspace.TemplateUrl}}</p>
                <hr />
                <div ng-include="{{workspace.TemplateUrl}}"></div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Controller code

```
 var Workspace = (function () {
        function Workspace(templateUrl, name) {
            this.TemplateUrl = templateUrl;
            this.Name = name;
        }
        return Workspace;
    })();
    function HostController($scope) {
        $scope.Workspaces = new Array();
        $scope.Workspaces.push(new Workspace("/app/templates/Template1.html", "Workspace 1"));
        $scope.Workspaces.push(new Workspace("/app/templates/Template2.html", "Workspace 2"));
        $scope.Workspaces.push(new Workspace("/app/templates/Template1.html", "Workspace 3"));
        $scope.Workspaces.push(new Workspace("/app/templates/Template2.html", "Workspace 4"));
        $scope.Workspaces.push(new Workspace("/app/templates/Template1.html", "Workspace 5"));
    }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I quote Your code

```
 <div ng-include="{{workspace.TemplateUrl}}"></div>
```

should be

```
 <div ng-include="workspace.TemplateUrl"></div>
```

since it is a ng statement.

Comment: Ahhh that's it! Fantastic!! I just assumed all bound values has to formatted like binding expressions.  One for me to remember going forward! :-)

Comment: It is a statement that gets evaluated directly so you dont need {{}}. it also means you cant put a string like ng-include="/templates/my-temp.html" in the ng-include you'll have to quote it like ng-include="'/templates/my-temp.html'" , like it is some javascript.